# Getting XML file content as string in php

Tags: php, xml

I want to display the content of a xml file as itself. I dont want to parse it, instead just read its content and display it.

I tried

```
$content = file_get_contents("test.xml") ;
```

But the `$content` has xml in it.ie when I `var_dump($content)` the output is `string(899) " "` 
 Is it possible to read the the file without parsing. Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [How to echo xml file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1199595/367456); [file_get_contents() returns an empty string when authenticating, otherwise fine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5954840/367456); [php - send and receive xml documents](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6779320/367456)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve it

```
$content = htmlentities(file_get_contents("test.xml"));
```

And this should solve it:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$content = file_get_contents("test.xml");
var_dump($content);
```

It tells the browser you're sending plain text so that the XML is not rendered as HTML tags (which then are unknown and hidden).