# Get HTML content and show this as plain text

Tags: php, html

I get content of a html file:

```
ob_start();
include ("myFile.html");
$html = ob_get_contents();
```

Now I would like to send $html as plain text via mail to show the code.
I tried `"<pre>".$html."</pre>"` and `"<code>".$html."</code>"`

But I get not the plain code. Can you help me?

Comment: Why not do `$html = file_get_contents()`?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting XML file content as string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235933/getting-xml-file-content-as-string-in-php)

Comment: You could display $html inside of a textarea element

Comment: ``htmlspecialchars($html)`` should do the work, even you can wrap under the ``<pre>htmlspecialchars($html)</pre>`` tag.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text

Comment: The other question is not entirely the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```php
<?php

$filePath = __DIR__ . '/myFile.html';

$content = file_get_contents($filePath);
// Escape.
$content = htmlspecialchars($content);
// Makes lines visible.
$content = preg_replace('/\n/', '<br>' . PHP_EOL, $content);

echo $content;
```

> Note that I use single-quotes to improve performance slightly, but when using double-quote, the pattern would be `"/\\n/"` (to escape Back-slash, but should work even without escaping).

Answer (score 1):

I know Top-Master answered this question, but this is an alternative method, that still uses `include`. I didn't know enough about PHP to know about the fancy methods, that are probably much more secure.

The `<pre>` tag doesn't guarantee that the contents will be displayed verbatim. For example `<pre><a>Hello</a></pre>` will show up as [Hello](https://example.com), not <a>Hello</a>. To solve this you can use &lt; (less than sign) and &rt; (greater than sign). If you need and actual ampersand ("&"), you can use &amp;.

This modified version should escape <, >, and &. Do not rely on this in terms of security.

```
ob_start();
include ("myFile.html");
$html = ob_get_contents();
$html = str_replace("&", "&amp;". $html);
$html = str_replace("<", "&lt;". $html);
$html = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $html);
$html = str_replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the HTML code in the browser just take [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) and set the header for Text/Plain.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
readfile("myFile.html");
```

To send HTML code via email, the HTML code can be copied from the browser or can be called up with file_get_contents(). The email format must then be set to plain text.